# Not able to mock the static method with powermockito?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

Getting the exception:

```
although stubbed methods may return mocks, you cannot inline mock creation (mock()) call inside a thenReturn method (see issue 53)
```

I am following the https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyUtil.class);

Mockito.when(MyUtil.compareVersion("1","2")).thenReturn(200);
```

Also I want to mock this class partial, there are others methods in this class, which I don't want to mock, they should run as usual.

Detailed Exception :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your code snippet but do you have the following annotations on your test class?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyUtil.class)
public class MyUtilTest {
```

Additionally, you should look at https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13 for newer versions of PowerMock.